# issue when trying to move a div up and down

Tags: javascript, html, css, smooth-scrolling

i'm trying to move the `div` with class `player` top and down when i click on the arrow keys using this code :

**JavaScript**

```
var playerPosition = 0;

window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if(key = 38) {
        playerPosition += 10;

    } else if(key = 40) {
        playerPosition -= 10;
    }

    var players = document.getElementsByClassName('player');
    for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
    players[i].style.marginTop = playerPosition+"px";

 }
```

the problem is when i hit any key the `div` goes down !

- http://jsfiddle.net/b5eaey58/

2nd problem that the movement of the div isn't smooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're calling the wrong operator, you're trying to evaluate `=` instead of `===`. (FYI You may have the keys reversed unless you want the `div` to go up when you press down) For it being not smooth it's because you're firing the function `onkeyup` which means the user has to release the key before the movement triggers. Use `onkeydown` instead so the user can hold down the key and make it run smoother:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b5eaey58/1/)

Comment: any solution to make the movement smoother ?

Comment: @ZeRuBuES you can try cutting down the distance it jumps so `+=5` instead of `+=10`, although that will make it take longer to move

Comment: @ZeRuBuES Don't forget to click the checkmark if jmore009's answer solves the question.

Comment: A linter would have caught this. https://jslinterrors.com/unexpected-assignment-expression